# How to get Wireless working with Ubuntu 11 Server?

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, hardware

When I install Ubuntu Desktop, I can use internet once I boot into Ubuntu, but with Server Edition, I can't. Somehow, wireless is not detected ... how can I install it either during install or post install. Suppose throughout the whole process, all I have is Wireless. So either I DL files using Desktop version then install Ubuntu Server or something

Comment: that's because the desktop comes with those extra drivers, the server edition doesn't.

Comment: @Uri Herrera, isit possible to install them somehow? Like perhaps browse to it, maybe its included in the ISO? no? Even if no, probably I can download those drivers into a thumbdrive or HDD and install it from there?

Comment: yes of course you can install them , you would only need to know which one's to install, they come but not in the server iso theycome on the desktop iso, though you'd be better off downloading them anyway staright into the server.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I think I can answer my own question...

I needed

```
wireless-tools network-manager-gnome
```

then running `nm-applet` and it will do the rest ... I think thats all ...